# ubuntu 18.04. Error mongodb "reason: Connection refused" Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb

gente, ¿como han estado?. 
necesito ayuda con este problema en mongodb,instalé mongo "sudo apt-get install mongo -y mongodb" y a la hora de probar con el estado de mongo el mensaje de error es que la conexión fue rechazada, probé con distintas soluciones como: mongod --repair, systemctl enable mongodb.service, systemctl start mongodb.service, reinstalar y ninguna me funcionó. 
les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: error mongodb connection refused]
[image: status mongodb.service]

Comment: Hay dice claramente que no puede leer el archivo de configuracion /etc/mongod.conf debes recrearlo https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, el error lo pude solucionar instalando la v4, desinstalando la v4 y volviendo a instalar la v3. no se exactamente por que se solucionó así.  
Esto lo hice antes de ver tu respuesta, de todas maneras muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo pude solucionar instalando la v4, desinstalando la v4 y volviendo a instalar la v3.